# Is this a valid identity for the expected value of a nonnegative random variable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, expectation

Say $Z$ is a nonnegative random variable. First we can describe the integer component of $Z$ as $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} I_{n\leq Z}$. Since $Z$ is always greater or equal to its integer component we have

$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[Z]
& \geq \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} I_{n\leq Z}\right]\\
& = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{E}\left[I_{n\leq Z}\right]\\
& = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}\left(Z\geq n\right).
\end{split}
$$

On the other hand we can also deduce the following.

$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[Z]
& = \int_\Omega Z\,d\mathbb{P}\\
& = \int_\Omega \int_{x=0}^Z dx\,d\mathbb{P}\\
& = \int_\Omega \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} I_{[0, Z]}\,dx\,d\mathbb{P}\\
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} \int_\Omega I_{[0, Z]}\,d\mathbb{P}\,dx\\
& = \int_{\mathbb{R^+}}\mathbb{P}\left(Z \geq x\right)\,dx
\end{split}
$$

These results I've seen in the literature, so I don't think I'm off so far. But now use the fact that $\mathbb{P}\left(Z \geq x \right)$ is a *decreasing* function of $x$ to write

$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[Z]
& = \int_{\mathbb{R^+}}\mathbb{P}\left(Z \geq x\right)\,dx\\
& = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int_{x=n}^{n+1}\mathbb{P}\left(Z \geq x\right)\,dx\\
& \leq \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}\left(Z \geq n\right).
\end{split}
$$

Finally, putting the first and last result together we arrive at

$$
\mathbb{E}[Z] = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}\left(Z \geq n\right).
$$

I'm a little perplexed that this result would hold for arbitrary nonnegative random variables. Is it actually correct?

Comment: It is correct for random variables that take nonnegative values and follows directly from $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}np_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^np_n=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{n=i}^{\infty}p_n$.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{N}$? Do you have $0\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. Also I know that this equality holds for nonnegative *integer* valued random variables. The point is that I didn't use that assumption here.

Comment: But then the integer part thing is not true, see my answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right to be perplexed. This would seem to imply that $E(\lfloor Z \rfloor) = E(Z) $ for all non-negative random variables. Say $Z$ is an exponential random variable. Then we have $$ \int_0^\infty P(Z\ge x) dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}dx = \frac{1}{\lambda}=E(Z)$$ as promised. But we have $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(Z\ge n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda n } = \frac{1}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$$ which is generally larger than $1/\lambda.$

So in fact your second inequality $$ E(Z) \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(Z\ge n)$$ seems to be the correct one.

What was wrong with the first one? After all, it came from the seemingly bulletproof argument that $$\lfloor Z\rfloor=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1(Z \ge n).$$ Except, wait... it's not. We have $$ 1 = \lfloor 1.1 \rfloor \ne 1+ 1 = 2.$$ This is overcounting by one. So in fact your first inequality should be $$E(Z) \ge -1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(Z\ge n).$$

This, perhaps more than anything, underscores the importance of never writing $$ \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} f(n)$$ and always writing $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)$ or $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n),$ whichever is appropriate.

Comment: whoops didn't see i was severely beaten to the punch

Answer (score 4):

I see where the mistake lies. First you say the integer part of $Z$ is $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} I_{\{n\leq Z \}}$ and this is only valid if $0\notin\mathbb{N}$. Alright? Now in your last lines you should have written the following:
\begin{align}
E[Z]&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}P(Z\geq x)\,dx\\
&=\color{red}{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int_{n-1}^nP(Z\geq x)\,dx}\\
&\leq \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}P(Z\geq n-1)
\end{align}
But then you cannot conclude what you have concluded first.

Actually I knew already that it is not true, but I was looking for the mistake. Take for example $Z\sim \exp(1)$ then $E[Z]=1$ but then the expresssion: $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} P(Z\geq n) =\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} e^{-n}\neq 1$$ in either cases $0\in\mathbb{N}$ or $0\notin\mathbb{N}$.

**Edit.** You have commented that $0\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, please, be consistent with everything, because the integer part of $Z$ would be $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}I_{\{n+1\leq Z\}}$

Comment: The inconsistency with $\mathbb{N}$ wasn't intentional. And actually that's exactly the key mistake in this whole thing.

Comment: @Michael thank you for pointing that out! I personally like to include $0$ but since everyone does it on his own way,  I'm confused and just say $\mathbb{N}_0$ to include $0$. Would be nice if everyone would do the same..

Comment: @SebastianOberhoff I knew that lol! The text on the last line is not meant to be rude or something. It took me some time to realise where the mistake was. This could be a good problem on find the mistake, because people will always jump to changing summation and integrals while in this case was due to the fact that not everybody uses $\mathbb{N}$ the same way.

Comment: @Shashi For fun, here is metaphysical justification for defining the natural numbers as $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, …\}$: The universe is natural.  If there was zero at the beginning, there would be zero now.  Since a nonzero universe exists, it did not arise from zero.  So zero is quite unnatural.

Comment: @Michael Good one hahaha!